# What class to use in newer version of Spring boot instead of SpringApplicationContextLoader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm very new in Spring world, so don't be hard on me.

I put together a Spring Data Rest application and I would like to test it in a Cucumber environment. At the moment I need the JPA repository injected into my StepDef classes to be able to insert data into the database.

So far, I have found two examples, [this](https://github.com/karlbennett/spring-boot-cucumber-example) and [this](https://github.com/elinger/cucumber-spring-boot-tutorial). But both of them are using spring-boot package before 1.3.4, where the SpringApplicationContextLoader class has been removed.

At this point I have a few questions:

- Do I have to use the latest spring boot in testing? (in my opinion I don't, at least it is not a crucial thing, these examples gave me some time to figure out how to use newer version of spring boot in my testing environment)
- Do you know any example about how the above examples should look like using 1.5.x version of Spring boot?